# Error on line 25, column 10: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In pubsec.yaml it gives this error.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier if you could include the YAML snippet, follow below post it will resolve the issue

Comment: it just wrong indentation

Answer (score 1):

The issue with indentation, follow

```yaml
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  english_words: ^4.0.0
```

dot indicates the number of space

[image]

Comment: Positioned you dependencies as `english_words`

Answer (score 0):

Take care with spaces. YAML is like Python, intentation matters. The dependencies `http`, `flutter` and `firebase_core` have the wrong indentation.

To fix it just do like the following:

```yaml
# The same before...

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.12.0+1
  firebase_core: ^1.21.0

# And so on...
```